# How to keep SQL tble field not updated when I update other fields in Visual Basic?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a class that allows me to update the sql table field. One of the fields that I want to update is the file name. The following function returns the file name based on some conditions. The problem that I am having is the `else` clause.

```
Public Function checkFileNamesForUpdate(ByVal file As FileUpload, ByVal firstName As String, ByVal lastName As String, ByVal text As String, ByVal hyper As HyperLink) As String
    If (file.HasFile) Then
        Return firstName.ToLower + "_" + lastName.ToLower + "_" + text
    ElseIf (Not file.HasFile AndAlso hyper.NavigateUrl <> "") Then
        Return firstName.ToLower + "_" + lastName.ToLower + "_" + text
    Else
        Return Nothing
    End If
End Function
```

`Return Nothing` is not going to update the table field which is `FileName`. I want it to be `NULL` value. So I have used `Return DBNull.Value.ToString()`. But this doesn't add null instead blank field.

Is there any approach that I am missing?

Comment: `DBNull.ToString()` returns and empty string so it makes sense that your update would be a blank field. You are on the right track with DBNull, however based on the fact that your function is returning a String, you may have to add an additional check after the function call to update your db with DBNull.Value if the function returns Nothing/Empty String

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can return "" of String.Empty in the Else section of your Function. The in the calling code check for String.IsNullOrEmpty and set the value of the parameter as shown.

```
Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim fileUp As New FileUpload
    Dim h As New Hyperlink
    Dim ReturnedString As String = checkFileNamesForUpdate(fileUp, "John", "Smith", "Some text", h)
    Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string"),
            cmd As New SqlCommand("Update SomeTable Set FileName = @FileName;")
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FileName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100)
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(ReturnedString) Then
            cmd.Parameters("@FileName").Value = DBNull.Value
        Else
            cmd.Parameters("@FileName").Value = ReturnedString
        End If
        cn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Sub
```